# MidiInPort.FromIdAsync no response no exception

Tags: windows, midi

I have a windows store app using `Windows.Devices.Midi`

There is a registered midi in device on my machine for a paired ipad, which is not connected.

When I call `await MidiInPort.FromIdAsync(inputId);` with the `inputId` being the above device it just hangs and doesn't throw or go to the next line.

How can I find out what is going wrong here?

Comment: Getting the ID worked correctly? Does that paired iPad MIDI port use a custom driver?

Comment: Yes, id was retrieved while the Ipad was paired and online via Bluetooth

Comment: Not sure if it uses a custom driver, but suspect so. I use an app MDXW which broadcasts a "virtual midi service"

Comment: I expect it to fail, but need it to throw so I can't catch and deal with it.. that it does nothing is the problem

Comment: Does this port work with other programs? Does your app work with other MIDI ports?

Comment: When the Ipad is connected all is good, yes my program works with other ports. The problem is the fact it hangs and doesn't throw when not connected

Comment: Are you using a static predefined device id, or are you enumerating connected devices to find the id of this device? You will need to enumerate (Windows Devices Enumeration  DeviceInformation::FindAllAsyncAqsFilter and others), and also watch for device changes (DeviceInformation::CreateWatcherAqsFilter). with the